# Why netlify is showing graph query error though in local, there is no error?

Tags: graphql, web-deployment, gatsby, netlify, gatsby-image

Well, I am trying to deploy a website in netlify. It is already in [github](https://github.com/ronyahammad/gatsby-restaurant-site)

When I am trying to deploy the website in netlify, it is showing errors [but on my local computer it is running without errors](https://pastebin.pl/view/bc3e82d7)

The website is running fine in the browser localhost and graphquery is showing data as desired. I made the menu list in contentful... so I had to make an gitignore .env.development file but I inserted CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN and CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID in netlify build environment variables.

What more can I do if there is no error showing while executing on localhost?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Using Gatsby environment variables + Netlify requires a small change in those variables. You need to add `GATSBY` prefix in all your variables. Like shows this [Netlify community thread](https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-access-environment-variables/1240/2) and also [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#example-of-using-an-environment-variable):

> Please note that you shouldn’t commit .env.* files to your source
>   control and rather use options given by your Continuous Deployment
>   (CD) provider. An example is Netlify with its build environment
>   variables.
>   Note: since Gatsby uses the Webpack DefinePlugin to make the
>   environment variables available at runtime, they cannot be
>   destructured from process.env; instead, they have to be fully
>   referenced.
>
> `GATSBY_API_URL` will be available to your site (Client-side and
>   server-side) as `process.env.GATSBY_API_URL`.:

Of course, this only applies to the Netlify side, not in your local machine but it is recommended to use the same naming on both sides. So you need to change your Contentful variables.

`CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` to `GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` and `CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID` to `GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID` (moreover in you `gatsby-config.js` or wherever you use them).

The next (and final) step is to add those variables in your Netlify dashboard like shows the following screenshot:

[image: Environment configuration]
The previous configuration can be found under *Deploys > Deploy settings*

Once you have done this, your front side will be able to find your Contentful variables. You may need to delete the Netlify build cache.

[image]

Comment: thanx for your detail reply and i have done exactly what you've said and you can check my repository where my config file is updated in same manner but still showing the same error. it is driving me crazy.my site is working in the browser but i dun know what else i can do.it's so bad: toFormat seems to be empty, we need a fileExtension to set it.
    1 | fragment GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG on ImageSharpFluid {
 PM:    2 |   tracedSVG
9:00:32 PM:    3 |   aspectRatio
9:00:32 PM:    4 |   src
9:00:32 PM:    5 |   srcSet
9:00:32 PM:    6 |   sizes
9:00:32 PM:    7 | }

Comment: Jeez, that's tricky. Your environment is working fine but throws an error on your GraphQL fragment. I'll check it out. Just to be sure, have you tried removing your Netlify build cache? I'll update my answer showing a screenshot.

Comment: Well it’s a work of one click. I mean when I click on trigger deploy there comes a option of clear cache and deploy. So if I’m right, I’m doing it everytime

Comment: well here is an update-.according to the stackoverflow question:58974472, i deleted all the TracedSVG and then update the repository and after that tried to deploy.. the error related to TracedSVG and unknown extension have gone but now i have a new problem: https://pastebin.pl/view/bc3e82d7. now all the official docs from gatsby and netlify is telling me to or suggesting to use "allContentfulCoffee" parameter and while using it,the page's menu section can fetch the desired data. now what else can be done.besides TracedSVG is the problem of their global production problem, wasting so much time

Comment: Do you have that element (Coffee) in your Contentful schema?

Comment: menu: allContentfulCoffee {
  edges {
    node {
      id
      title
      desription {
        desription
      }
      price
      category
      image {
        fixed(width: 50, height: 50) {
      src
        }
      }
    }
  }
} here is the whole querry and in contentful there are two items under CoffeeItem, one is Coffee and another one is Product. i wanted to make a product buy option by snipcart but i didn't. least i wanted to see what i did. besides my querry could fetch all the data and it was showing in the webpage under the correct allignment....